# Using getString for Integer

Tags: android, json

{"id":56754}

For the above JSON, if I use jsonResp.getString("id"), it works fine, It also works for  jsonResp.getInt("id").

Does it mean getString is like the parent for all the specific methods?

Comment: What library do you use to parse JSON?

Answer (score 0):

## Methods don't inherit

> This keeps in tune with the java Type hierarchy

`getString` and `getInt` are two completely different methods. I get what you are trying to say, there's no method overloading or `getInt` doesn't call `getString` either.

As is obvious, `getString` returns a `String` and `getInt` returns an `int`. So `56754` here can be **interpreted** as either a String or an int. Here's more, this would work even with `getLong` and `getDouble` too. As `56754` can be treated as a long or a double too.

Answer (score 0):

According to Source - not exactly:

```
public String getString(String key) throws JSONException {
    return get(key).toString();
 }
```

while

```
public int getInt(String key) throws JSONException {
     Object o = get(key);
     return o instanceof Number ?
     ((Number)o).intValue() : (int)getDouble(key);
 }
```

Both of this method use the same method `get` and then parse result in correct way.